# Select all nodes except one in XML using XQuery

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, xpath, xquery

I have following XML Document:

```
<RapportV4Type xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="urn:oio:ebst:diadem:4">
    <RapportResume xmlns="urn:oio:ebst:diadem:resume:1">
        <RapportvalgmulighedSamling>
            <Rapportvalgmulighed>
                <RapportResumeTekst>Ja</RapportResumeTekst>
                <RapportvalgmulighedIdentifikator xmlns="urn:oio:ebst:diadem:1">00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000056</RapportvalgmulighedIdentifikator>
            </Rapportvalgmulighed>
            <Rapportvalgmulighed>
                <RapportResumeTekst>Ja</RapportResumeTekst>
                <RapportvalgmulighedIdentifikator xmlns="urn:oio:ebst:diadem:1">00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000011</RapportvalgmulighedIdentifikator>
            </Rapportvalgmulighed>
        </RapportvalgmulighedSamling>
    </RapportResume>
</RapportV4Type>
```

And I'm making an sql query including following

```
Rapportvalgmulighed[diadem1:RapportvalgmulighedIdentifikator = "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000056"].
```

which successfully selects the node which has the value : 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000056 in "RapportvalgmulighedIdentifikator" field.

"diadem1" is defined as following namespace : "urn:oio:ebst:diadem:1".

I want to change the logic now, and select all nodes except the one I'm defining in the selector. So how do I select all nodes except the one with value: 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000056 in RapportvalgmulighedIdentifikator field ?.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand this correctly, reversing that particular logic can be done simply by using `not()` :

```
Rapportvalgmulighed[
    not(diadem1:RapportvalgmulighedIdentifikator = "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000056")
]
```

If each `Rapportvalgmulighed` can have only one `RapportvalgmulighedIdentifikator` child, then using `!=` should work to :

```
Rapportvalgmulighed[
    diadem1:RapportvalgmulighedIdentifikator != "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000056"
]
```